# CVS repository missing connection types

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I'm new to using CVS repositories. I'm trying to import a repo by right clicking in the CVS repositories area, New -> Repository Location and then a window pops up with Add CVS repository. Under connection type, in Eclipse Luna I have 'extssh', but in Eclipse Mars I only have 'ext' and 'pserver'.

I need to use extssh. What is it and how do I configure it?

Comment: @HarsH1610 yes, I just had to install some other CVS plug-ins, as described by HarsH1610

Answer (score 2):

Install CVS plugin from below link:-
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios

Then search for "CVS"and select "Eclipse CVS Client" and install it.

Note- 
This worked for me in STS and Eclipse 2018-12.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note on this - I was also looking to use extssh with Oxygen because anything much later than Oxygen 4.7.3a doesn't appear to support WebSphere 7.0 >:(.

I had to uninstall the Oxygen instance of CVS Client by going to Help/About/Installation Details and uninstalling it.  Then I was able to install the Helios version Naveen mentioned above and it worked.